# Confusion About Definition of Handedness in Knot Theory

Tags: definition, knot-theory

I read that to determine the handedness of a crossing, you look at a small, almost-straight segment of rope that has the overcrossing. You then check to see if that segment has an overall slope that is negative or positive. If it is positive, then it is right-handed. Otherwise, it is left-handed.

But what if the slope is $0$?

For reference, here is the link: [https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgar/Teach/2008_MA3F2/lecture1.pdf](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emasgar/Teach/2008_MA3F2/lecture1.pdf). Thanks

Comment: It would seem to make sense to regard the rope being crossed as the $x$ axis, which a straight segment could not overcross with slope zero.  It would not matter if you had it upside down because the slope would be the same either way.

Comment: First, you are not talking about handedness of the whole knot, just the sign of  single crossing. The way I think about this is to imagine curling my right hand around the top strand so that my thumb points in the strand direction. Then the sign is determined by whether my fingers brushing the bottom strand go with it or against it.

Comment: @rschwieb Do you have a reference for that the rope being crossed is the x-axis? Thanks!

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Thanks, I apologize, I fixed it now

Comment: @MeltedStatementRecognizing No, I'm just guessing what the obvious solution is: that they never intended it to be possible for the segment to have zero slope, because what it crosses probably has zero slope.  Those notes are loose in a few places, it seems. Or at least, there are gaps that I fall into as well.

Comment: Your reference says: "*in the standard diagram* of the right-handed crossing the overpassing arc has positive slope." The standard diagram is the X shape shown above that passage.

Comment: @Théophile I know. I don't understand your point

Comment: My point is that in an X shape (more specifically, an X shape with both lines oriented upward), one line is going to the top left, and the other is going to the top right. In other words, one has negative slope, and the other has positive slope; neither has slope $0$. If your crossing does have a part with slope $0$, then it doesn't correspond to a standard diagram; rotate it so that it does.

Comment: @Théophile thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of a knot diagram in the plane requires a number of properties:

1. The projection needs to be an immersion; this means it has to be smooth with no cusps.
2. Whenever the projection intersects itself, the two intersecting curves cannot be tangent to one another. (Equivalently, the tangent vectors at the crossing point have to span $\mathbb{R}^2$.)
3. The only self-intersections are double points (so there cannot be three different points projected to the same point)>

The second property, from the perspective of the notes, is exactly that the slope is not $0$.

In short, the reason the slope isn't $0$ is because by definition knot diagrams aren't allowed to have slope-$0$ crossings. It's possible to prove that every knot has a diagram that satisfies all the properties, using something like Sard's theorem.